# Angular Spinner Hide Function Doesn't Work

Tags: angular, typescript, fuse

In my app, I have a spinner  which stops after `GET` functions are done. For one screen, the spinner doesn't hide even though `GET` functions looks done in the network. The counter never becomes 0. What could be the problem?

Spinner Service:

```
private _spinner: FuseSpinnerComponent;
    private _callCount: number = 0;
    public hide(): void {
    
            this._callCount--;
            if (this._spinner && this._callCount <= 0) {
                this._spinner.Hide();
            }
        }
```

HTTP Service:

```
get(url: string, contentType?: ContentTypes): Observable<any> {

    this._spinner.show();

    return this._http.get(this.baseUri + url, { headers: this.getHeader(contentType) }).pipe(
        catchError((err: any) => this.handleError(err)),
        finalize(() => {
            this._spinner.hide();
        }),);
}
```

The Screen:

```
if (state.url.indexOf("/admin/contact-list") >= 0) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Promise.all([
                    this.getContactList(),
                    this.getGeoTypeList(),
                    this.getSectorTypeList(),
                ]).then(
                    ([results]) => {
                        resolve([]);
                    },
                    reject
                );
            });
        }

    getContactList() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._http
                .get("Crm/GetContactList/")
                .subscribe((response: IContact[]) => {
                    this.contactList = response;
                    this.onContactListChanged.next(
                        this.contactList
                    );
                    resolve(this.contactList);
                }, reject);
        });
    }
        getGeoTypeList(): Observable<IGeoType[]> {
        return this._http.get("Parameter/GetGeoTypeList");
    }

    getSectorTypeList(): Observable<IGeoType[]> {
        return this._http.get("Parameter/GetSectorTypeList");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Http client requests are cold, you have to subscribe to them to get the data.

```
get(url: string, contentType?: ContentTypes): Observable<any> {

this._spinner.show();

return this._http.get(this.baseUri + url, { headers: 
  this.getHeader(contentType) }).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => this.handleError(err)),
   }).subscribe( _ => this._spinner.hide())
    );
}
```